# check_kvm_support script failed to start error when attempting to create VM

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, multipass

When I attempt to initialise a VM on Debian 10 instance I am getting an error :

```
multipass launch --name kube-master --cpus 1 --mem 1024M --disk 3G


launch failed: The check_kvm_support script failed to start. Ensure it is in multipassd's PATH.
```

I checked virtualization parameters and the instance has Microsoft virtualization (not kvm):

```
lscpu
CPU family:          6
Model:               63
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz
Stepping:            2
CPU MHz:             2596.991
BogoMIPS:            5193.98
Hypervisor vendor:   Microsoft
Virtualization type: full
```

I have attempted to enable virtualization as per suggestions but it appears since I have Microsoft I cannot  :

```
 kvm-ok
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

I have tried the suggested fix command :

```
sudo modprobe kvm intel
```

and retried to initialize the VM but Im still getting the same error.

My question - How do I enable virtualization when my underlying virtualization provider is of type Microsoft (and not kvm)?

This is my system details :

```
  Icon name: computer-vm
       Chassis: vm
    Machine ID: 2096d4c088f84a09bcf4e4f7bb730aac
       Boot ID: 27760bc0b01848a182d7e53f00acad9e
Virtualization: microsoft
```

Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Kernel: Linux 5.10.0-0.bpo.9-amd64
Architecture: x86-64

Answer (score 1):

this is a known issue of multipass that will be fixed soon as of Jan 2022: https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/2336

you can install multipass from edge channel

`sudo snap install multipass --channel=edge`

and check:

1. The system's CPU supports virtualization.
2. Virtualization is enabled in the system BIOS.
   `